# AWS Ec2 - Scp File Transfer Permission Denied

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, scp

I have followed the documentation provided to be able to transfer local files to a directory found within the ec2 instance, but I keep getting a `Permission denied` with the path and file in my ec2 instance prepended to the error.

This shouldn't be an issue with credentials, because I `ssh` with the same commands without any issue. What I am curious about is possibly the file and folder permissions within my ec2 instance or locally and if that is preventing the transfer.

Sidenote: Not sure if this matters, but when I `ssh` with same credentials, I am brought to `/home/ec2-user` and when I run `ls -a` I don't see `/var/app` listed, but can `cd` into it without any issues and find my app.

**Full error message:**

```
scp: /var/app/current/config/pk-cfappkey.pem: Permission denied
```

**Here is my scp command:**

```
scp -vvv -i /Users/user/.ssh/app-key-pair /Users/user/Desktop/Projects/node/project/config/pk-cfappkey.pem ec2-user@ec2-[id].compute-1.amazonaws.com:/var/app/current/config
```

**Here are my folder and file permissions**

**Ec2 Instance folder path:**

```
/var/app/current/config
drwxr-xr-x  2 nodejs nodejs 4096 Oct  9 14:35 config
```

local file (pk-cfappkey.pem):

```
-rw-r--r--@ 1 user  staff  1706 Sep 24 15:09 pk-cfappkey.pem
```

Detailed error message (summarized):

```
debug1: Connecting to ec2-[id].compute-1.amazonaws.com [id] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug2: callback start
debug1: Sending command: scp -v -t /var/app/current/config
debug2: channel 0: request exec confirm 1
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: exec request accepted on channel 0
Sending file modes: C0644 1706 pk-cfappkey.pem
debug2: channel 0: rcvd ext data 45
Sink: C0644 1706 pk-cfappkey.pem
debug2: channel 0: written 45 to efd 8
scp: /var/app/current/config/pk-cfappkey.pem: Permission denied
debug2: channel 0: read<=0 rfd 6 len 0
debug2: channel 0: read failed
debug2: channel 0: close_read
debug2: channel 0: input open -> drain
debug2: channel 0: ibuf empty
debug2: channel 0: send eof
debug2: channel 0: input drain -> closed
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
scp: /var/app/current/config/pk-cfappkey.pem: Permission denied
```

Your user `ec2-user` does not have write access to the directory `/var/app/current/config/`. You should copy the file elsewhere:

```
scp -vvv -i /Users/user/.ssh/app-key-pair \
  /Users/user/Desktop/Projects/node/project/config/pk-cfappkey.pem \
  ec2-user@ec2-[id].compute-1.amazonaws.com:
```

then connect to the server:

```
ssh ec2-user@ec2-[id].compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

and move it to the proper location with appropriate `sudo` access:

```
sudo cp pk-cfappkey.pem /var/app/current/config/
```

Answer (score 10):

update the destination folder permission with

```
chmod 777 -R /destination/folder/location
```